# enumerability axiomas 1 implies 2 and vice versa

Tags: general-topology

Be $X$ a topological space and $x \in X$. Prove that $x$ admits a fundamental system of enumerable neighbourhoods if, and only if, there is a local base in $x$ that is enumtable.

Definition. Be $X$ a topological space:

1. If each point of space $X$ has a fundamental system of enumerable neighbors, we say that it satisfies the first enumerability axiom.
2. When $X$ has an enumerable base we say that $X$ satisfies the second enumerability axiom.
3. When $X$ is separable (that is, it has an enumerable dense set) then we say that $X$ satisfies the third enumerability axiom.

(i) What this exercise says is that the first enumerability axiom implies the second enumerability axiom?
(ii) Can I consider the elements of this neighbourhood system to be the elements of the base, and vice versa? If so, then this demonstration is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

A space that satisfies your first axiom of enumerability is called a *first countable* space; one that satisfies your second axiom is called a *second countable* space.

It is not true that every first countable space is second countable: for instance, an uncountable space with the discrete topology is first countable but not second countable. Let $x\in X$; the exercise is to show that there is a countable fundamental system of nbhds of $x$ if and only if there is a countable local base at $x$.

Yes, if there is a countable local base $\mathscr{B}$ at $x$, then $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable fundamental system of nbhds of $x$. You have to work a little harder for the other direction. Let $\mathscr{N}$ be a countable fundamental system of nbhds of $x$. Then for each $N\in\mathscr{N}$ there is an open set $B_N$ such that $x\in B_N\subseteq N$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_N:N\in\mathscr{N}\}$; $\mathscr{B}$ is countable, so to finish the proof you just have to show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a local base at $x$.